# gcc 7.2 and nvptx nvidia gpu offloading

Tags: gcc, openmp, nvidia, offloading

gcc supports offloading openmp code to nvidia cards since gcc version 7.1 but I'm unable to use it. I'm on ubuntu 17.10 and I have installed `nvptx-tools` and `gcc-offload-nvptx` packages. when I try to compile openmp target code I get this error

```
ptxas /tmp/ccqGsx2p.o, line 383; error   : State space mismatch between instruction and address in instruction 'ld'
ptxas /tmp/ccqGsx2p.o, line 456; error   : State space mismatch between instruction and address in instruction 'ld'
ptxas /tmp/ccqGsx2p.o, line 383; error   : Unknown symbol '__stack_chk_guard'
ptxas /tmp/ccqGsx2p.o, line 383; fatal   : Label expected for forward reference of '__stack_chk_guard'
ptxas fatal   : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors
nvptx-as: ptxas returned 255 exit status
mkoffload: fatal error: x86_64-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc-7 returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
lto-wrapper: fatal error: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7//accel/nvptx-none/mkoffload returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I was unable to find any solutions for this and openmp in gcc with nvptx support has almost no documentaion

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81730

Comment: What is your compilation string (e.g. `g++ -fopenmp main.cpp`)?

Comment: @Richard I don't remember now (it's been a while) but it did include an `-nvptx` flag along with `-fopenmp`

Comment: This same issue (`__stack_chk_guard`) occurs for me with GCC 7.2.

Comment: `g++ -O3 -Wall foo.cpp -fopenmp -foffload=nvptx-none -fno-stack-protector`.